# Laravelのバリデーションでregexを指定すると、入力フォームで空欄が送信できなくなる。

Tags: php, laravel

Laravelを使って、入力フォームを作成しています。
バリデーションのルールで正規表現を使って、**４桁の数字、または空欄**を指定して、入力チェックを行いたいのですが、regexを指定した時点で空欄がバリデーションに引っかかってしまいます。

例えば、

```
$rules = [
    'value1' => ['regex:/^\d{4}$/'],
    'value2' => ['regex:/^(\d{4})?$/']
    'value3' => ['regex:/^(\d{4}|\s*)$/'],
    'value4' => ['regex:/^(\d{4}|\n*)$/'],
    'value5' => ['regex:/^(\d{4}| *)$/']
];
```

このような方法は試しましたが、空欄で送信するとバリデーションに引っかかります。
この他にも考えられる方法は試してみましたが、出来ません。
そもそもregexを設定した時点で空欄も無効になっている気がします。

```
'value' => ['regex:/\s*/']
```

ちなみに\dを抜いて、↑のような方法や

```
'value' => ['regex:/.*/']
```

↑も試しましたが、両記とも全角スペースだと通りますが、半角スペース、空欄の場合はダメでした。

どのように設定すれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: [本家に同種の質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46755642/6541007)が挙がっています。承認された回答はありませんが、`nullable`を使えってのが使えそうに見えます。`'value' => ['nullable|regex:/^\d{4}$/'],`なんてのはうまくいきませんか?

Comment: @OOPer   出来ました！！質問の重複で申し訳ありません。パイプではエラーが出てしまいましたが、      'value' => ['nullable','regex:/^\d{4}$/'],    これで上手くいきました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。特に検証もしていないコードお試しいただけて助かります。お手数ですが、このサイトでは自己解決(コメントをヒントにした時も含めて)した場合、自己回答することが推奨されています。(「コメント」と「回答」は全くの別物。)是非うまくいった内容を回答として投稿してください。

Comment: 了解です。ご丁寧にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

nullableを使うことで設定することが出来ました。

```
'value' => ['nullable','regex:/^\d{4}$/'],
```

正規表現に付け足すのではなく、1つのバリデーションを設定します。

regex内で **| (パイプ)** を使う際は、バリデートを分けるために **| (パイプ)** が使用できないため配列型で設定しますが、この場合必要ないので、

```
'value' => 'nullable | regex:/^\d{4}$/',
```

これで出来ました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: 回答の投稿ありがとうございます。わかりやすい解説もつけていただき、こちらも勉強になります。質問直後はすぐに自己回答の「承認」はできないのですが、後ほど承認もお願いします。今後も質問・回答を問わず、このサイトのQ&Aを充実させるのにご協力いただければ嬉しいです。